# Geometry of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be the following matrices:
\begin{align*} 
&\mathbf{A} \text{ rotates vectors clockwise by a right angle},\\
&\mathbf{B} \text{ projects vectors onto a line with direction $\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 4 \end{pmatrix} $}.\\
\end{align*}Calculate the matrix
$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B} \begin{pmatrix} -4  & 1 \\ 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}.$$

I tried solving this problem by finding matrices that fit with what the problem says A and B do, but I'm not even sure if you need to find A and B to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can always construct matrices based on what they do to the basis vectors. Given
$$\boldsymbol e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}~,~\boldsymbol e_2=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$
The basis vectors, and letting
$$\mathbf A=\begin{bmatrix}A^1{}_1 & A^1{}_2 \\ A^2{}_1 & A^2{}_2\end{bmatrix}$$
Be our matrix, the columns of the matrix can be found by
$$\begin{bmatrix}A^1{}_i \\ A^2{}_i\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf A\boldsymbol e_i$$

Let $\mathbf R(\theta)$ be the 2D rotation matrix that rotates vectors (counterclockwise!) by an angle of $\theta$. We know that
$$\mathbf R(\theta)\boldsymbol e_1=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$$
Since $e_2$ is just $e_1$ rotated by an angle of $\pi/2$, we know that
$$\mathbf R(\theta)\boldsymbol e_2=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta+\pi/2) \\ \sin(\theta+\pi/2)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-\sin(\theta) \\ \cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$$
Hence
$$\mathbf R(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$
So the matrix that rotates vectors **clockwise** by an angle of ninety degrees or $\pi/2$ is just
$$\boxed{\mathbf R(-\pi/2)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}}$$

---

As for the other matrix, it is a *projection* matrix. It extracts the portion of a vector that is aligned with another vector.

As seen in the below diagram, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection)

[image: projection]

The projection of the vector $\boldsymbol a$ onto vector $\boldsymbol b$ points in the direction of $\boldsymbol b$, and has a magnitude of $|a|\cos\theta$, where $\theta=\frac{ a\cdot  b}{|a||b|}$ is the angle separating the vectors.

Therefore, in general, the projection matrix $\mathbf P(\boldsymbol v)$ that projects vectors onto the vector $v$ is the linear map
$$\boldsymbol u\mapsto \mathbf P(\boldsymbol v)\boldsymbol u=|u|\cos\left(\frac{u\cdot v}{|u||v|}\right)~\frac{\boldsymbol v}{|v|}$$

Therefore,
$$\mathbf P(\boldsymbol v)\boldsymbol e_1=\mathbf P(\boldsymbol v)\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}=|(1,0)^\intercal|\cos\left(\frac{v \cdot(1,0)^\intercal}{|(1,0)^\intercal||v|}\right)\frac{\boldsymbol v}{|v|}=\cos\left(\frac{v^1}{|v|}\right)\frac{\boldsymbol v}{|v|}$$
Similarly
$$\mathbf P(\boldsymbol v)\boldsymbol e_2=\cos\left(\frac{v^2}{|v|}\right)\frac{\boldsymbol v}{|v|}$$

And so in all
$$\mathbf P(\boldsymbol v)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\left(\frac{v^1}{|v|}\right)\frac{v^1}{|v|} & \cos\left(\frac{v^2}{|v|}\right)\frac{v^1}{|v|} \\ \cos\left(\frac{v^1}{|v|}\right)\frac{v^2}{|v|} & \cos\left(\frac{v^2}{|v|}\right)\frac{v^2}{|v|}\end{bmatrix}$$

So in the case that $\boldsymbol v=(1,4)^\intercal$ as in your case you can work out
$$\boxed{\mathbf P\big((1,4)^\intercal\big)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}\begin{bmatrix}\cos(1/\sqrt{17}) & \cos(4/\sqrt{17}) \\ 4\cos(1/\sqrt{17}) & 4\cos(4/\sqrt{17})\end{bmatrix}}$$

Now the last step is to calculate

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix} ~ \frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}\begin{bmatrix}\cos(1/\sqrt{17}) & \cos(4/\sqrt{17}) \\ 4\cos(1/\sqrt{17}) & 4\cos(4/\sqrt{17})\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-4 & 1 \\ 1 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$
Which I trust you can do yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can calculate the cosines...

Comment: @TristanLi With a calculator? Or you can just leave them like that.

Comment: oh, also, i realized we don't need to find A and B, we can just use the vector transformations